# AngularJS ng-Repeat directive issues

Tags: angularjs

trying to simply return server data back to an ng-repeat directive on my HTML, but it's rendering blank `<li>` elements:

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="dim in settings.dimenDS">{{dim.data.name}}</li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

In my javascript controller code:

```
 (function () {
 'use strict';
  angular.module('rage')
   .controller('GridSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',  'datacontext', 'widget', gridSettings]);

 function gridSettings($scope, $modalInstance, datacontext, widget) {

    var settings = this;

    settings.myName = "Bob Mazzo";

settings.dimenDS = getDimFromServer();
function getDimFromServer() {
        datacontext.getDimensionsFromServer().then(
        function (data) {
            return data;
        }
    );
    }

};   // end of gridSettings()    
})();
```

The setup for the Angular-Bootstrap modal window which contains my HTML is :

```
 settingsModalOptions: {   // config popup
      templateUrl: 'app/shared/include/grid-config/widget-config-grid.html',
      controller: 'GridSettingsCtrl as settings'
 }
```

The `data` object has the following schema :

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"messages": [],
"data": [
    {
        "name": "Snapshot_Id",
        "type": "integer"
    },
    {
        "name": "tradeId",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "dealId",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "BookingCountry",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "BookingLocation",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Broker",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "BuySell",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "CCY2",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "CloseOutNettingAgreementId",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "CollateralAgreementId",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Counterparty",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "DealDate",
        "type": "timestamp"
    },
    {
        "name": "DealIssuer",
        "type": "varchar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Delta",
        "type": "float"
    }              
]
}
```

I'll keep troubleshooting. In the meantime, your advice is appreciated.

thanks,
Bob

Comment: In the `then` you need to return `data.data`, $http `then`s  are resolved with the response object and not just with the response body.

Comment: `settings.dimenDS` needs to be on the `$scope` to be able to be accessed from the view. Also, given the format of your response, you need to do as commented above (return data.data) or change your `ng-repeat` to loop through `settings.dimenDS.data` and display `dim.name`.

Comment: @DavidSpence - it is on the scope using the "controller as" syntax - `controller: 'GridSettingsCtrl as settings'`. See the amended post above. thank you.

Comment: @bob - It isn't on the scope. All that the that just renames the controller so that you can type it easier going forward. I suggest that you download this chrome extension, [Batarang Stable](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek?hl=en-US). With it you can view what is in scope, and what is out of scope.

Comment: @kshreve - I was thinking of my data being "in scope" in the generic sense. However I see your point as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController . That is, using `"controller as"` does not put it on the angular $scope object. Rather it binds properties directly onto the controller. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: guys - It turns out the `return data.data` will not properly bind. I needed this line in my `then()` section - `settings.dimenDS = data.data;  `. Doing it this way I can return either "data" or "data.data", and then the HTML code could be either "settings.dimenDS" or "settings.dimenDS.data" as per both your comments.

Comment: @bob I did notice that you weren't setting the result within your `then` but I thought you knew something I didn't :)

Comment: @DavidSpence - I understand what you mean, and that was def my error. I thought it would bind to my object using "return" but I was wrong. How do I handle the final answer to this post ?

Comment: @bob Just post the answer yourself and mark it as the answer. It might help the next person!

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly bind the `settings.dimenDS` data object to the view, I removed the `return` within the `then()` section and assigned `data.data` directly to the object :

```
   settings.dimenDS = getDimFromServer();

    function getDimFromServer() {
        datacontext.getDimensionsFromServer().then(
        function (data) {
            settings.dimenDS = data.data;                
        }
    );
    }
```

and the final html markup:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="dim-list" kendo-sortable k-placeholder="settings.placeholder" k-hint="settings.hint">
            <li ng-repeat="dim in settings.dimenDS">{{dim.name}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```